# Why this equation of absolute value of exponential function,complex number holds or even is this equation correct?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, polar-coordinates, absolute-value

I've written the below 2 claims.

*Claim1.*

$$   \left| \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \right|=\prod_{i=1}^{n} \left|a_{i} \right|$$

$$  \left\{ a \right\} :=\text{sequence which holds} ~a_{i} \in\mathbb{R} $$

$$n:=n(a)$$

*Proof.*

$$  \left\{ b   \right\} :=\text{sequence which holds}~ \left| a_{i} \right| \cdot (-1)^{b_{i}} = a_{i}~~~ \text{by} ~~~b_{i} \in\left\{0,1\right\}  $$

$$   \left| \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \right|= \left|\prod_{ i=1 }^{ n } \left| a_{i} \right| \left( -1 \right) ^{b_{i}} \right|  $$

$$=\left|\left(-1\right)^{\text{0 or 1}}\prod_{ i=1 }^{ n } \left| a_{i} \right| \right|  $$

$$=\left|\prod_{ i=1 }^{ n } \left| a_{i} \right| \right|  $$

$$=\prod_{ i=1 }^{ n } \left| a_{i} \right|$$

$$   \left| \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \right|=\prod_{i=1}^{n} \left|a_{i} \right|$$

$$  \text{QED.} $$

*Claim2.*

$$  a,b,c \in\mathbb{R} $$

$$j:=\text{imaginary number}$$

$$  \left| a+b \exp\left(- j\omega  \right) + c \exp\left(- 2j\omega \right)  \right| =  \left| a+b \exp\left( j\omega  \right) + c \exp\left( 2j\omega \right)  \right|  $$

*Proof.*

$$  \left| a+b \exp\left(- j\omega  \right) + c \exp\left(- 2j\omega \right)  \right| =  \left| a+b \exp\left( j\omega  \right) + c \exp\left( 2j\omega \right)  \right|  $$

$$  \left| a\exp\left(j \cdot 0\right) +b \exp\left(- j\omega  \right) + c \exp\left(- 2j\omega \right)  \right| =  \left| a\exp\left(j \cdot 0\right)+b \exp\left( j\omega  \right) + c \exp\left( 2j\omega \right)  \right|  $$

I assumed the each  absolute value inside the absolute value bars as sum of each magnitude of vector of 2d cartesian system( or polar coordinates syetem). So the equation holds.

I've drawn the below rough image.
[image]

However if we develop the exponential functions,

$$  \left| a+b \exp\left(- j\omega  \right) + c \exp\left(- 2j\omega \right)  \right| =  \left| a+b \exp\left( j\omega  \right) + c \exp\left( 2j\omega \right)  \right|  $$

$$  \left| a+b \left( \cos\left(-\omega \right) +j\sin\left(-\omega \right)  \right)  + c \left( \cos\left(-2 \omega \right) +j\sin\left(-2 \omega \right)  \right)   \right| =  \left| a+b \left( \cos\left(\omega \right) +j\sin\left(\omega \right)  \right)  + c \left( \cos\left(2 \omega \right) +j\sin\left(2 \omega \right)  \right)   \right|  $$

$$  \left| a+b \left( \cos\left(\omega \right) -j\sin\left(\omega \right)  \right)  + c \left( \cos\left(2 \omega \right) -j\sin\left(2 \omega \right)  \right)   \right| =  \left| a+b \left( \cos\left(\omega \right) +j\sin\left(\omega \right)  \right)  + c \left( \cos\left(2 \omega \right) +j\sin\left(2 \omega \right)  \right)   \right|  $$

$$  \left| a+b  \cos\left(\omega \right) -bj\sin\left(\omega \right)   + c  \cos\left(2 \omega \right) -cj\sin\left(2 \omega   \right)   \right| =  \left| a+b  \cos\left(\omega \right) +bj\sin\left(\omega \right)    + c  \cos\left(2 \omega \right) +cj\sin\left(2 \omega   \right)   \right|  $$

So ,of above equation,$ ~~a ~,~ b \cos\left(\omega \right) ~,~  c \cos\left(2 \omega \right)  $ are shared in each formula however the signs of $ b j\sin\left(\omega\right) ~,~ c j\sin\left( \omega \right)   $ are opposite.

So seemingly I think that the equation cannot be held.

What I've been missing?

Comment: Counterexample for claim 1: $|1 + (-1)| \ne |1| + |-1|$?

Comment: Sorry I made mistake I should have to write PI than sigma. I'll edit now.

Comment: @mechatronicsenthusiast Guess you meant $\sin(\omega)$, not $\sin(j \omega)$, and same for $\cos$. Just use that $|z| = |\bar z|$.

Comment: I'll fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Your proof for the first claim is a little odd, but not wrong. You really just need to show that $|a\cdot b|=|a|\cdot|b|$. You can prove this fact directly from the definition of absolute value by analyzing the four different cases for the signs of $a$ and $b$. For example: when $a$ and $b$ are both nonnegative, $|a|=a$ and $|b|=b$ and $a\cdot b$ is nonnegative too, thus $|a\cdot b|=a\cdot b=|a|\cdot|b|$. Etc for the other cases.

Comment: Using that equation recursively is more simpler(good) I think.Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Claim 2, you have a small typo from mis-applying Euler's formula. You should end up with

$$|a + b \cos \omega - ib \sin \omega + c \cos (2\omega) - ic \sin (2\omega)|
= |a + b \cos \omega + ib \sin \omega + c \cos (2\omega) + ic \sin (2\omega)|$$

Then using the fact that $|p+jq|^2 = p^2 + q^2$ when $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$, you can check that the square of both sides of the above equation are
$$(a+b \cos \omega + c \cos (2\omega))^2 + (b \sin \omega + c \sin (2\omega))^2.$$

Comment: I confiremd that each square of both sides is same.

So as we define $L,R:=\text{each absolute value of the equation}~~~$

the below is true.

$$L^{2}=R^{2} ~~\Leftrightarrow~~L=R \left( \because L,R \geq0 \right)   $$


I'll press mark of check. Thank you.